# Trying to execute procrank from cmd promt, but not working

Tags: android, shell, adb, dumpsys

I'm trying to get memory info which is allocated by my specific application using **"adb shell procrank".**
But when i'm trying to execute the procrank command from cmd promt its giving me error like **"/system/bin/sh: procrank: not found"**.
I cant guess what it means!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procrank is not installed on all devices, you will have to use the following command: "adb shell dumpsys meminfo", it won't give you the memory usage per app, but its an alternative.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Alexander. 
is there is any way to install procrank in to my device(i'm using moto g)?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can search for a rom for your phone, which has it, or alternatively just try to extract it from a rom :)